# How to automatically record the arrival timestamp when the data arrives into the database

Tags: c++, timestamp, dolphindb

In the GUI, when adding data, I can use timestamp(now()) to generate it. But what if I send data through the c++ API? How to generate the timestamp when it arrives in the database, instead of sending it over after it is generated on the c++ client. How to achieve it?

Comment: Show code. Your question is impossible to answer as it is.

Answer (score 0):

In dolphindb, The function "now" is used to get the current timestamp and the function "timestamp" is used to return the time in TIMESTAMP type.

If C++ API is connected, the timestamp needs to be generated in C++.

In fact, the DolphinDB GUI is based on the Java API. The function timestamp(now()) returning timestamps is also generated on the client. So if you want to record the arrival timestamp, you should complete the operation in C++ client.